# Returning table type in table union in SQL

Tags: sql, union-all

I have union of two tables, these tables don't have column type, but I need to return table name (or similar identification) so I can know in my code which table it was from. I'm using  Microsoft SQL Server 2008 R2.

Here is my current SQL, that doesn't return type yet.

```
select Id, Name, CHAR(0) as Type 
  from Table1 
union all 
select Id, Name, CHAR(1) as Type 
  from Table2;
```

Comment: select Id, Name, 'Table1' as TableType from Table1 union all select Id, Name, 'Table2' as TableType from Table2

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The solution:

```
select Id, Name, 'Table_1' as Type from Table1 
union all 
select Id, Name, 'Table_2' as Type from Table2;
```

Answer (score 2):

How about this:

```
select 'Table1' as Type, Id, Name from Table1 
union all select 'Table2' as type, Id, Name from Table2;
```